# Slope-One recommender algorithm performance

Tags: performance, mahout, collaborative-filtering

I am building a slope one based recommender. The system has 40 million users and 1 million items. Each user has rated around 10 items.
The deviation matrix is calculated as part of batch processing and is loaded in memory ( putting into a distributed cache)

The issue i am facing is performance at runtime !!!
At run-time for recommendenation for a user the logic is as follows:
for each item not rated by user (this num is quite high = 1 million - 10)
  for each item rated by user (10)
     calculate the avg deviation 
     ...

Now the fundamental issue is the outer loop is too high ( 1 million - 10). Doing some many calculations at runtime will never perform !

Have you guys solved this issue ? Is there a trick to reduce this computaion at runtime ?

Thanks,
Siddharth